# How to create a database and run ef core migration in docker?

Tags: docker, entity-framework-core

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/nightly/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyApi.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./MyApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "MyApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApi.dll"]

RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh
CMD /bin/bash ./entrypoint.sh
```

This is entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
run_cmd="dotnet run --server.urls http://*:80"

until dotnet ef database update; do
>&2 echo "SQL Server is starting up"
sleep 1
done

>&2 echo "SQL Server is up - executing command"
exec $run_cmd
sleep 10

>&2 echo "Creating Database"
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S db -U sa -P P@55w0rd -i create-database.sql
```

This is create-database.sql

```
USE master
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'Demo')
BEGIN
  CREATE DATABASE Demo;
END;
GO
```

But when I run it, I got this error

```
#17 0.615 chmod: cannot access './entrypoint.sh': No such file or directory
#17 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh]: exit code: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is not in the directory in which you think it is.

Remember that the `WORKDIR` command is effectively `cd` for your `Dockerfile`. Let's take a close look at the sequence of events in your question.

1. In the first stage, you have `WORKDIR /src`. You copy files from your local directory into the `/src` directory:

   ```
   FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build

   WORKDIR /src
   COPY ["MyApi.csproj", "."]
   COPY . .
   ```
2. In your `final` phase, you copy files from `/app/publish` into `/app`:

   ```
   FROM base AS final

   WORKDIR /app
   COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
   ```
3. Your `CMD` attempts to run `entrypoint.sh` in current directory, which is `/app` because of that `WORKDIR /app` directive:

   ```
   CMD bash entrypoint.sh
   ```

However, you never explicitly move `entrypoint.sh` from `/src` to `/app/publish`, and while I'm not familiar with the `dotnet publish` command, I'm guessing that it doesn't move that file for you, either.

The solution is to make sure that `entrypoint.sh` gets moved into `/app`. The simplest solution may be to just copy it in explicitly in your `final` stage:

```
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
COPY entrypoint.sh /app/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApi.dll"]

CMD /bin/bash ./entrypoint.sh
```

Comment: I can run without error now but it doesn't create the database as expected.

Comment: That seems like a different issue. I think this answer accurately addresses your original question. You should probably open a new question regarding database creation.